# Virtual Keyboard doesn't appear when rotate the screen?

Tags: android, layout

I am facing to a problem related virtual keyboard.

I've created a layout that contains Button, TextView and EditText.

When its screen orientation is Portrait, it can show the Virtual Keyboard by one touching on the EditText.

Then I've changed screen orientation to Landscape. At this moment Virtual Keyboard hasn't been appeared.

What is wrong here ?

How to fix it ?

I think this is big problem for my application.

Please help. guys.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Last Time I create a keyboard for Android ( I used Android 1.0 ) and I'm not sure this issue still remains or not.

The issue was if you implement a keyboard you had to determine orientation and then rotate it programmatically, so there was no chance to do that in version 1.0.

But I heard that for now (Android 2.1) there is now problem and the screen rotate keyboard automatically.

Comment: Thanks, So. 
Do I need to upgrade Android SDK to 2.1 ?

I am using Platform 1.5. Will application that I compiled on 1.5 work on OS 2.1 or upper ?

Comment: My application works on 2.1, and I didn't change anything but I recommand to use 2.1, it is free and you can easily upgrade and I think there will be nothing to change but alwaysthere are some consideration. and about your keyboard I really don't know what will happen in V2.1 because Idon't work with 2.1 SDK

Comment: There is no change I know of in the behavior of when an IME appears in Android 2.1  This answer is actually really odd because IMEs weren't even in the platform until 1.5 (not in 1.0).  Also an IME does NOT need to determine the orientation it definitely does not need to "rotate programmatically."  Just look at the sample IME code to see.

The main reason an IME will not be shown is because the InputMethodService base class by default does not display itself when there is a hard keyboard available.  When you rotate the emulator, you are also flipping the lid making a hard keyboard available.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I don't know about IME. What is IME ?
Can you give a link about IME ?